# wxpython beautiful widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

As I was looking into the widget creations tutorial in wxpython. I saw that all of them has the window look but I want a widget like the one you can see on windows 7 (clock widget etc.) or like the one advanced systemcare has.

So my question how can I make such a widget in wxpython if I can at all?

Answer (score 0):

wxPython will look like the OS's native widgets. If you need to do something more advanced, then you'll have to write your own widget. There are lots of examples of custom widgets included with wxPython. Take a look at anything in wx.lib.agw. All of those are custom made widgets, written in Python.

Here are a couple of other links:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls
- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/customwidgets/